# maximization and minimization

Tags: optimization

> Show that $f(x_1^*,...x_n^*)=\max\{f(x_1,...,x_n):(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Omega\}$ if and only if
>   $-f(x_1^*,...x_n^*)=\min\{-f(x_1,...,x_n):(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Omega\}$

I am not exactly sure how to approach this problem -- it is very general, so I can't assume anything about the shape of $f$. It seems obvious that flipping the $\max$ problem with a negative turns it into a $\min$ problem. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the chain of equivalences here:

$$\begin{align}
& f(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)=\max\{f(x_1,...,x_n):(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Omega\} \\
\iff & (x_1^*,...,x_n^*) \in \Omega \text{ and } \forall (x_1,...,x_n)\in\Omega, f(x_1^*,...x_n^*) \geq f(x_1,...,x_n) \\
\iff & (x_1^*,...,x_n^*) \in \Omega \text{ and } \forall (x_1,...,x_n)\in\Omega, -f(x_1^*,...,x_n^*) \leq -f(x_1,...,x_n) \\
\iff & -f(x_1^*,...,x_n^*)=\min\{-f(x_1,...,x_n):(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Omega\}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I came across this question when it was recently bumped to the front page, so I wrapped your chain of equivalences in an `align` environment. Hope that's OK.

Comment: Great! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just multiply 
$$\forall \mathbf y \in \Omega,\qquad\max(f(\mathbf x): \mathbf x \in \Omega)\ge f(\mathbf y)$$
with $-1$?

Comment: One cannot recommend the use of a same symbol in the maximum on the LHS and as an argument in the RHS.

Comment: “Bureaucrat Conrad, you are technically correct — the best kind of correct.” (Futurama, 2acv11: How Hermes Requisitioned His Groove Back)